# Python cumsum of rows up until n-1

Tags: python, dataframe, cumsum

I am trying to get a cumulative sum of a column in a dataframe for all rows except the row we are interested in. The dataframe is split by year.

I have been able to do this in excel and the below is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I am close by using

`df1['CumSum'] =  df1.groupby('Year')['Value'].cumsum()`

but this will return

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `shift` on the groups to shift the result by one:

```py
df["CumSum"] = df.groupby("Year", group_keys=False)["Value"].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(1))
```